# Summing rectifier outputs

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have a situation where I need to sum the output voltages of 2 rectifiers.  One is a full wave bridge on a 350 VAC center tapped secondary, and the 2nd one is a bridge rectifier on a 70 VAC secondary.  How can I sum those 2 DC voltages?

Comment: Are they floating as is no shared node in between them?

Comment: You might want to include more context on what you are really trying to do. These voltages are unusual.

Answer (score 1):

If they are both (or technically at least one) isolated transformers, you hook the positive of one to the negative of the other after the rectification. The sum will be across the two free leads/terminals. But to be honest, if you are really asking this, you should not be the guy hooking this up. These are lethal voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhQFO3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Unloaded, you should get nominally a little over 590DC.

**UPDATEED**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flC9GS.png)</sup>

This could be simplified more if the transformers are in phase and operating at the same frequency.

Comment: There are likely other considerations but, at a minimum, the transformers must be fed from the same supply phase.

Comment: @vir I would agree if the outputs were unfiltered, the caps are too small, or the load is too high. In general, the phasing doesn't matter in what I've arranged.

Comment: You failed to notice that one rectifier is a bridge, and the other is full wave, with a grounded center tap on that transformer.  But, not to worry, as I already figured it out.  I'd be glad to post the schematic, but don't see how to do so!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to upload schematics?  Thanks!

Comment: @bluesteve Fine, Steve. Updated to better match your question. And as Vir's comment reminded me, this could be simpler with a few assumptions. BTW, there is a schematic editor in the text box toolbar that pops up when your posting.

Comment: @bluesteve: when editing your question, use the "mountains" icon to upload a picture, or use control-M to open a Circuit Lab window where you can draw your schematic, then insert it in your message.

Comment: Mosfet - Thanks!  Actually, that's almost exactly what I came up with, except I forgot C1!  I really appreciate your time with this.  THANKS!

Comment: Peter - Thanks for the help, but I still don't see how to upload.  I don't see any kind of a mountain icon here.  What am I missing?!